# Форма обратной связи в интернет магазине

Tags: java, spring, bootstrap, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Здраствуйте
Имеется проект интернет магазина. Там присутствуют различные магазины(Магазин камер продает видео камер, магазин телевизоров телевизоры и тд.)У каждого магазина есть своя страница, где отображаются все товары этого магазина. Необходимо сделать форму обратной связи. Чтобы при заходе на страницу магазина она была, либо модальное окно либо переходом на отдельную страницу. Приложение на springboot

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Например заходя на страницу где-нибудь внизу будет форма с полями Имя, Почта/ номер телефона, Комментарий. Примеры обратной связи, именно код, ищите в интернете или пишите сами. Редактируете под свой шаблонизатор, дабы шла обработка запроса. Предварительно создаете таблицу в БД и репозиторий. Пишите контроллеры для отображения и получения запроса. Со стороны клиента это возможность написать, со стороны администратора или сотрудника магазина увидеть комментарий и далее выслать ответ на почту или позвонить по номеру телефона.

Если что-то конкретное интересует, то приводите пример с кодом для конкретного ответа. А пока Ваш вопрос несет обширный характер